# JavaFX CSS theming via @import and variables

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-css

I have taken to assigning variables to frequently-used colors in my JavaFX CSS and referencing the variables rather than the color constants:

```
* {
    theme-backgroundDark: #335588;
}

#messageListPane {
    -fx-background-color: theme-backgroundDark;
}
```

Now I want to take the block where I define the color variable names and move it to a separate .css file. This will allow me to swap out different .css files at runtime to change the application's theme:

**Theme1.css**

```
* {
    theme-backgroundDark: #335588;
}
```

**Main.css**

```
@import url( "/styles/Theme1.css" );

#messageListPane {
    -fx-background-color: theme-backgroundDark;
}
```

But when I do this JavaFX is unable to find the variables at runtime:

```
WARNING: Could not resolve 'theme-backgroundDark' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*#messageListPane ' in stylesheet file:/C:/xxxx/styles/Main.css
```

It's not a problem with the `@import` statement; I have other `@import`s that define class selectors and those get picked up just fine in `Main.css`.  It seems to have something to do with the wildcard selector `* { ... }`.

So why would named color variables in a wildcard selector work in the same CSS but not when imported from another CSS?

Comment: I don't think the scope of the named color variables should be affected by if it is inline in a file or in an imported file: You might want to [file an issue in the JavaFX tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: Ok, @jewelsea, I've done so: [RT-40287](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40287).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The named colors are fine.  My @import statement is being ignored, simple as that.  If I attach Themes.css manually via code, the named colors are visible.  The @import statement is not picking up the themes file and not giving me any type of error.  I'll open another question for that.

Comment: Could you please share the link to "antoher question" you've mentioned? I'm having similar problems

Comment: I haven't looked at this project in years, but digging it out of storage and looking at it it doesn't appear that I ever solved the problem -- there are no @import statements to be found :-(  I think I performed the imports in code.

Comment: I also had to merge css files programatically via URL stream handler - thing I wanted to do in couple of hours took me almost 2 days :D